# How can I create a mariadb drop in replacement for MAMP

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mamp

I am currently using MAMP, and would like to create a dropin replacement to use mariadb instead. I am not sure how to do this. Would anyone have an idea on how to do that? Thanks!